# Subclass using operator= from base class

Tags: c++

I have the following classes

```
class Interval
{
public:
     Interval& operator=(Interval const &interval);
}
```

and

```
class SubInterval : public Interval
{
    public:

       SubInterval& operator=(SubInterval const &interval)
       {
         cout<<"SUB_ASSIGNMENT"<<endl;
         if( this != &interval)
         {
            Interval::operator=(interval);
            
         }
          return *this;
       }
}
```

Now I am creating two pointers

```
    Interval* interval = new SubInterval(1,20,"sampleInterval",2);
   Interval* interval2 = new SubInterval(2,5,"abc",5);
```

and when I do
  `*interval2 = *interval;`
I expect the operator= of SubInterval to be called then the operator= of Interval , however only the operator= of Interval is called. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: The method in the base class should be virtual.

Comment: Only by making `Interval::operator=` virtual, and overriding it in the subclass. This is what virtual methods are for.

Comment: As I understand :
 ```virtual Interval& operator=(Interval const &interval); ``` in Interval and 
```Interval& operator=(Interval const &interval) override; ``` in SubInterval , but this will lead to casting , is there a way to escape it?

Comment: @Danilo, `interval` as the right side of the assignment is of type `Interval*` so you're not going to escape a cast somewhere if you want to treat it as a `SubInterval*`. You could, for example, use `std::variant` and `std::visit` to achieve something closer to multimethods and not have any explicit cast, but inheritance-based polymorphism puts you out of luck there because the language simply doesn't support multimethods through it. Pattern matching will probably be an option in the future, but not yet.

Comment: An extra virtual dispatch will avoid casting.

Comment: `*interval2 = *interval;` contains an `=` operator with 2 operands of type `Interval&`; so the compiler does not consider any member operators of `SubInterval`. Furthermore even if it did, `Interval&` is not assignable to `SubInterval const&`.